# could not find function "new_overscope" when running collect() from dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I am using R studio V3.5.1 on a server.

Below codes were to retrieve some data from a certain table in a database. The codes worked until today when I was rerunning the chunk. I got such an error message from this: Error in new_overscope(symbol_env, top_env) : could not find function "new_overscope". Then I figured out new_overscope() is an outdated function in 'rlang' package so I attached rlang (V 1.0.2) to see if I could get some luck to deal with the error, but it didn't work. And I happened to notice I have two versions of 'rlang' packages in different library paths. The earlier version I had was V 0.4.10.

I also tried to run the codes line by line, and it looked like all the lines before "collect()" worked fine. Now I have no idea whether the error does matter with either of the rlang packages, or are there any conflicts among the packages I had attached. I tried dplyr::collect() instead of collect() as well, no luck again.

Anyone experienced similar issue before? I would greatly appreciate hints or solutions!!

```r
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyverse)
library(pander)
library(broom)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(scales)
library(DBI)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dat <- connectToDB ('DB') %>% 
  tbl(sql("table")) %>% 
  select(var1, var2, var3) %>% 
  filter(var2 %like% "main") %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  arrange(var3) %>% 
  collect()
```